# Efficiently searching for a value in an ordered matrix

Tags: numerical-methods

I have a matrix with increasing numbers in each row direction (to the right) and each column direction (downwards), and seek to find the location of a particular number in the matrix or at least the location of entry that is closest to it if the number is not in the matrix. What would be the most computationally efficient way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

Binary search middle row, then recurse on lower left and upper right sub matrixes.

This is the best and last solution described in the link below:
http://articles.leetcode.com/2010/10/searching-2d-sorted-matrix.html

Answer (score 0):

[Binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) is one typical solution for arrays. Your matrix is basically a fragmented array, but it's very simple to adopt the same logic.

Comment: I was thinking of a strategy along these lines: For a large matrix one could approximate its coordinates as real numbers and could locate an isoline, then search the discrete matrix along that isoline to find a solution more efficiently than a binary search. Have to flesh out the details, if indeed that makes sense at all...

Comment: Unless there is some predefined structure / rules to the values in your matrix (which your doesn't question mention), I don't understand your comment.

Comment: There is a predefined structure; the matrix is monotonically increasing in both directions.

Comment: Change your question, add this (crucial) detail, and show a sample.

Comment: This detail is indeed crucial, which is why is was already in the question at the outset. Example: {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}.

Comment: Did you really think the matrix is simply a fragmented array ? That would mean the question is simplistic....